# How to plot worldmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, country-codes, geom

I'm working on a project and a small part of it consists of drawing a world map with 43 countries on my list. My dataset is as follows:

[image]

How do I put this on the world map with different colors for development status as follows?

[image]

Data is here :

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0960ed96fba15e9591a2e9c14ac852fa20220301181615/dc25f41a87fc2ba165a72ab6712dd8d020220301181640/832b5e

Comment: I think you will have a great answer if you share your data. You can use dput(head(data)) to select a subset of your df. I suggest you take a look at this post about making reproducible examples in SO: stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/…

Comment: hi, first of all thanks for your answer:) i added my data and link is here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0960ed96fba15e9591a2e9c14ac852fa20220301181615/dc25f41a87fc2ba165a72ab6712dd8d020220301181640/832b5e

Answer (score 2):

A quick example using fake data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# simulate data for subset of countries
mydata <- map_data("world") %>% 
  distinct(region) %>% 
  mutate(fakedata = runif(n())) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 200)

# add simulated values and remove Antarctica
worldmap <- map_data("world") %>% 
  filter(region != "Antarctica") %>% 
  left_join(mydata)

ggplot(worldmap) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = fakedata)) +
  coord_quickmap() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", na.value = NA) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Also look into the [{sf}](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) package and `geom_sf()`, which among other things makes it easier to use different / less distorted / less biased map projections.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @zephryl answer, but using `tmap`. The first step is joining your data with the `World` data by country name. The next step is drawing the map.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

# Get World data
data("World")

# Dummy data frame similar to your data
df <- data.frame(location = World$name,
                 devStat = rnorm(length(World$name), 5, 2.5))

# Join by country name
# Just need to make sure that country names are written exactly the same
# in the two datasets
df2 <- World |>
  left_join(df, by = c("name" = "location"))

# Create map
# Shape to add to the map
tm_shape(df2) +
  # Draw the previous shape as polygons
  # Set the attribute to which the polygons will be coloured
  tm_polygons("devStat", 
              # select palette
              palette = "-plasma",
              # Set palette categories as order
              style = "order",
              # Horizontal legend
              legend.is.portrait = FALSE) +
  # Remove frame from layout
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE,
            # Put legend outsize the frame
            legend.outside = T,
            legend.outside.position = "top")
```

[image: map]

Comment: how can i get world data?

Comment: `data("World")`